# PrimeFaces 3.0 - <p:dataTable> headers do not line up with using scrollable="true"

Tags: java, css, datatable, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a JSF 2 webapp that is using PrimeFaces 3.0 components. On one page, I'm using the `<p:dataTable>` component inside a composite component to display a table of objects. I've had success with this component until I tried to use the `scrollable="true"` option. Now the table column headers do not line up with the column content. I have tried using IE 7 (which is the target browser for my client environment) and Firefox 4.0.1 for comparison. Both exhibit the problem, but it is more pronounced in IE 7.

***IE 7 screenshot***:

[image: IE 7 screenshot]

***Firefox 4.0.1 screenshot***:

[image: Firefox 4.0.1 screenshot]

Here is some of my Facelet page code:

```
<p:dataTable
        id="vesselsDataTable"
        value="#{cc.attrs.vesselAdapterList}"
        var="currentRow"
        selection="#{editVesselBean.selectedRow}"
        selectionMode="single"
        scrollable="true"
        height="500">
    <p:column
            id="imoColumn"
            style="width:45px"
            sortBy="#{currentRow.imo}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="IMO" />
        </f:facet>
        <div class="#{currentRow.imoStyleClass}">
            <h:outputText value="#{currentRow.imo}"
        </div>
    </p:column>
    <p:column
            id="notesIndicatorColumn"
            style="width:35px"
            sortBy="#{currentRow.hasNotes}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{bundle.labelNotes}" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText 
            styleClass="noteIndicator"
            id="vesselNotesIndicator"
            value="#{bundle.stringNoteIndicatorText}"
            title="#{currentRow.notesAsTooltipText}"
            rendered="#{currentRow.hasNotes}"
    </p:column>
    <ui:remove>other column definitions omitted for brevity...</ui:remove>
<p:dataTable>
```

Each of my columns has a style with a fixed width in pixels defined, and the dataTable itself has the `height` attribute set. This seems to be the same as what is shown in the Showcase demo and in the 2.2 manual PDF.

To quote the manual:

> *Scrolling is a way to display data with fixed headers, in order to enable simple scrolling set scrollable options to true, define a fixed height in pixels and set a fixed width to each column.*

**Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?**

I'm using the current PrimeFaces 3.0-M2-SNAPSHOT with the current Mojarra 2.1 JSF RI.

**UPDATE**

I have moved to the PrimeFaces 3.0-M2 (not snapshot) release and the problem still exists. Following the suggestions by Maple and BalusC, I have (temporarily) removed the column sorting and tried different doc types. I finally settled on the XHTML 1.0 Strict doc type. It does not show any improvement in IE 7, but does show some improvement in Firefox 4.

**IE 7 with XHTML 1.0 Strict**

[image: IE 7 with XHTML 1.0 Strict]

**Firefox 4 with XHTML 1.0 Strict**

[image: Firefox 4 with XHTML 1.0 Strict]

The `<p:dataTable>` is inside a `<p:panel>` which is inside a `<p:layout>`. Could this be related?

Comment: It almost looks like on Firefox 4 that the header offset difference is roughly equal to the width of the scrollbar.  I notice you have a themeroller, does this header width change at all when you switch themes?

Comment: I checked the Primefaces issues page http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/list and didn't find this issue listed as a known bug.  It looks like it might be an issue of setting fixed widths to a column, on a scrollable dataTable, on Firefox and earlier versions of IE.  On a side note, THANK YOU for taking the time to write a clear and concise question.  I am becoming demoralized by the number of terrible questions on this site.

Comment: What happens when you remove the `sortBy` attribute of the column.  Perhaps there are CSS styles in the sort button DOM elements that are getting in the way?

Comment: Thanks for your comments Maple. I'm off for Canada Day so I'll take a look at this again on Monday at the office.

Comment: I removed all the `sortBy` attributes in the columns of this table. It did not fix the problem. With the sorting out I can see that each column header is slightly too small, so with many columns the misalignment is quite large at the end.

Comment: Problem still present in Primefaces 3.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is clearly a CSS/JS issue. A scrollable table with fixed headers is impossible in plain HTML (if `tbody { overflow: scroll; }` were supported by *all* browsers...). [A lot](http://www.google.com/search?q=scrollable+table+fixed+header) of different CSS/JS solutions(hacks) have been invented to achieve this. I don't have insight in PF 3 source and I don't know which hack it is using. But this definitely needs to be [reported](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/list) to the PF guys. The only thing which you can do is to check if you're using [the proper HTML doctype](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/) (read: a *strict* doctype) so that at least MSIE doesn't run in [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug).

E.g. HTML5

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

or XHTML 1.1

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<f:view contentType="text/html">
```

or XHTML 1.0 Strict

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<f:view contentType="text/html">
```

or maybe XHTML 1.0 Transitional

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<f:view contentType="text/html">
```

Comment: I have switched to XHTML 1.1. In IE 7 it still looks like total crap. In Firefox 4, it is almost correct but looks like it is misaligned by 1 pixel. Unfortunately, my user environment is 100% Internet Explorer (a mix of IE 6 and IE 7 right now) so looking nice in Firefox does me no good.

Comment: Likely PrimeFaces CSS is written with XHTML 1.0 Transitional in mind. Does that not work for you as well? Then report it as a PF bug.

Comment: Posted to http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=13509 per their rules for defect reporting. Will add to their defect tracker when I get the ok from a PF developer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is being discussed [here on the PrimeFaces support forum](http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=13509&p=41171#p41171).

As of today (July 20th, 2011) the problem can now be seen in the Labs Showcase hosted by PrimeFaces when using Internet Explorer 7.0 to view it:

[image: Screenshot of PrimeFaces Labs Showcase]

**EDIT:** Fixed as of today's PrimeFaces 3.0-M3-SNAPSHOT nightly build (July 22 2011).

Comment: I have Primefaces 5.1 and the headers still don't line up for me. I am using a scrollable datatable that is inside of another datatable via a <p:rowExpansion> element.

Comment: I am also experiencing this issue with Primefaces 5.1

Answer (score 0):

I had this same annoying misaligned header and footer problem on two projects with PF 3.4.1.
Playing with  header didn't help.

Seems to be fixed in PF 3.5.